# Flutter and translated buttons for showAboutDialog

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a button to display info about my app that works fine:

```
onTap: () async {
                PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
                return showAboutDialog(
                  context: context,
                  applicationName: translate('title'),
                  applicationVersion: packageInfo.version,
                  children: [
                    Image(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/brand/icon.jpg'),
                      height: 100,
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
```

The problem is that the "View licenses" and "Close" buttons are not translated on real time. I need to refresh the whole app to get them translated:
[image]
*(check that the language was updated but the buttons still not in English)*

And this is the code that make the language change:

```
 onChanged: (String newLang) async {
                  // update dropdown language
                  _language = newLang;
                  // update app language
                  changeLocale(context, newLang);
                  // save language
                  final options = json.decode(_prefs.get('options'));
                  options["language"] = newLang;
                  _prefs.setString('options', json.encode(options));
                  Provider.of<MyRents>(context, listen: false)
                      .updateLanguage(newLang);
                },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `showAboutDialog()` method will always display two buttons in the system's language (for you that seems to be Spanish). If you want a different behaviour, you will have to develop a custom dialog

Comment: I thought it could be possible to translate this part. Thanks for letting me know